# How can I run a javascript code when redirecting to another site ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

I really got confused . I have a website that getting menues from database and these menues redirecting to another aspx page using master page with this tag below.

```
<a href="<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>"><%# Eval("text") %></href>
```

I wanna show loading gif will start when I click one of these menues and it'll end when the redirecting page is ready. I tried preload method and javascript methods to do this. Every time javascript starting when the page completely ready.I can do this inside the page is loading again but as I've just said when redirecting it's not working. In the first I wanted do this for one page and tried the code below. But I need to this in the master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preloadFunc() {
        alert("PreLoad");
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
</script>
```

How can do this ? The master page code that I meant is below.

```
<div id="menu">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="button">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>">
                                    <%# Eval("text") %></a>
                                    <%-- menü kısmını çektiğimiz kısım  anamenü gelir --%>
                                    <div class="dropdown_1column align_right">
                                        <div class=" col_1">
                                            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("ChildItems") %>'>
                                                <%-- anamenünün altında gelicekleri çağırır. --%>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <a href="<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>">
                                                        <%# Eval("text") %>
                                                        </href>
                                                        <br />
                                                        <br />
                                                        <%-- menü url adreslerini çağırır. --%>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <SeparatorTemplate>
                                                </SeparatorTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </div>
```

Thanks for replies..

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the time of bring menu form database. I suggest to get meu data just one time and store them in session or in Cash if the menu data is the same  for all user.

You should NOT read the menu every time from database.

Comment: I'm doing that in  if(!isPostBack) method so i didn't read every time

Comment: Master Page Page_Load Event will be executed in every page event you use  if(!isPostBack)  >